# How to selectively turn specific highlight group on and off from vim session?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
hi SpellBad ctermfg=7 ctermbg=0* cterm=underline
hi Nonascii ctermbg=Black ctermfg=Red cterm=none
hi [...]
```

Some config files I need to look at contains so many unknown words that the highlighting defined in that highlighting group actually becomes a hindrance for visualization.

I am not looking for `:syntax off` followed by `:syntax on`. Obviously for any highlight group I could just issue `:hi clear highlight-group`. But then I'd be left with how to restore highlighting within the same session, without having to type in the exact line as it stands in the `.vimrc`  file.

Any thoughts on how to selectively (exclusively) turn off and back on specific highlight groups, within a `vim` session, would be appreciated.

***Edit:***
Just to be precise, I mean the question to be more general than just its specialization to the SpellBad highlight group. I have a few other highlight groups that I need to turn off and on from within a session.

Comment: Do you have `set spell` in your `vimrc`? If yes, remove it. If no, you can check who set `spell` by executing `:verbose set spell?`.

Comment: Just use `set spell! `

Comment: @klaus, Ralf : tx but oops, wasn't thinking this morning.  My question was a bit more general than the spell-checking example though. See my edit which clarifies it.

Comment: I can't remember but there is a way you should be able to know what the highlight group of the word under cursor and then you can store the  current highlight of that group in a temp global variable. Then use hi clear and when done, turn it back on with the stored variable. I can't do it myself now, I'm in phone. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Turn of spell checking, as suggested in the comments:

```
:set nospell
```

With [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired): `yos`

Comment: As suggested indeed. but my question was meant to be more general than the spell-checking example though. See my edit which clarifies it.